# Множественный вызов события OnGetText в компоненте DbGridEh

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Использую связку Delphi 10.2 + EhLib 9 + Direct Oracle Access, ситуация следующая.

В гриде (DBGridEh) есть много вычислимых (calculated) полей. Их значения формируются SQL-запросом, который прикручен к обработчику OnGetText в датасете. Ранее проект жил на Delphi7+EhLib3 и производительность такого решения была приемлема.

Но с переходом на Delphi10+EhLib9 производительность резко упала, навигация по записям стала очень медленной, отклик от грида сильно замедлился.

Стали разбираться почему. Оказалось, что **причина - это на порядок увеличившееся количество вызовов события OnGetText**. Оно инициируется гридом множество раз, даже от единственного движения мыши по вычислимому столбцу, а при клике на ячейку таблицы количество вызовов достигает сотни! Естественно, что запросы, навешанные на это событие, многократно выполняясь, тормозят работу с таблицей.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную проблему.

Comment: Почему значение этих полей нельзя сразу возвращать из базы? Зачем запросы дергать в событии?

Comment: Это было сделано для того, чтобы ускорить открытие датасета, на котором построена таблица. Кроме того, значения некоторых вычислимых полей зависят от динамического параметра.

Comment: Тогда делайте запрос только один раз и запоминайте делали ли вы уже запрос. Но подсчитать сразу будет быстрее

Comment: Спасибо. Кэширование на стороне клиента рассматриваю как вариант решения. Однако хотелось бы понять, можно ли уменьшить количество вызовов OnGetText штатными средствами.

Comment: Смотрите исходники EhLib

Comment: скорее всего что `OnGetText` вызывается для каждой ячейки грида.

Comment: Исходников для EhLib 9 нет, использую пока что демо-версию.

Comment: Для сравнения, стандартный DbGrid генерирует 2 вызова OnGetText при клике на ячейке, а DbGridEh около 100.